# Clear dynamic UserControl container

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I make _dynamicMaterials empty or clear the viewstate?

When the user clicks on submit I want to reset the container so all textboxes are empty.

Any ideas how I can work this out?

```
    private materials[] _dynamicMaterials; // Container for dynamically added UserControl "materials.ascx"

    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetPostBackControl(Page);
    }


    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            int count = MySession.Current.UserControlCount;
            _dynamicMaterials = new materials[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 1)
            {
                Control newcont = LoadControl("materials.ascx");
                newcont.ID = "materialControl" + i.ToString();
                myPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newcont);
                _dynamicMaterials[i] = (materials)newcont;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `ViewState.Clear();`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.statebag.clear.aspx

Comment: ViewState.clear(); does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you even need to track ViewState for that container, but assuming you don't the simplest solution would be to set `EnableViewState` to false on the container:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <!-- your controls here -->
</asp:Panel>
```

If you do need ViewState and you only want to clear it on submit, you can call `ViewState.Clear()` as others have suggested in the comments.

Lastly, you could also go through and clear the fields programmatically on submit:

```
pnlContent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(t => t.Text = string.Empty);
```